# How to extract props passed via react router link (v6) in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have a component `Main.tsx` that controls an API call. The response from this API call is saved to state as  and passed as props to `Photo.tsx` 
`Photos.tsx` renders  photos from the returned API call; these photos also acts as a link to the component `PhotoDetails.tsx`, which displays the individual photo as well as additional information. 
So state is passed as follows:

Main.tsx (passed as props to Photo.tsx as `photo`) ---> Photo.tsx (passed via Link as `state` to PhotoDetails.tsx) -->PhotoDetails.tsx

In `PhotoDetails.tsx` I want to then destructure the state passed from the router Link, but I'm getting the error

> Property 'state' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren'

Any ideas on how to fix my interfaces, so I can extract the props?

Code:

***Main.tsx***

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'
import Photo from './components/Photo'
import './styles.css'

export interface IPhoto {
    copyright:string,
    date:string,
    explanation:string,
    hdurl:string,
    media_type:string,
    service_version:string,
    title:string,
    url:string
}

export interface IPhotoComponent{
  photo:IPhoto,
  key:number
}

export interface DateRange {
  startDate:string,
  endDate:string
}

export type PhotosApiPayLoad = IPhoto[]

const Main = ():JSX.Element => {

  const [ photos,setPhoto ] = useState<IPhoto[]>([])
  const [ {startDate, endDate}, setDate ] = useState<DateRange>({startDate:'',endDate:''})

  const getData = async (): Promise<void> => {
    await axios.get<PhotosApiPayLoad>(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=*****&start_date=${startDate}&end_date=${endDate}`)
    .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
      setPhoto(response.data)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  },[startDate,endDate])


  const handleChange = (e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>):void => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {name,value} = e.target as HTMLInputElement
    setDate((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Nasa: Astronomy photo of the day!</h1>
      <div className='inputs'>
      <label>
        Enter start date
        <input type = 'date' name = 'startDate' onChange={handleChange} value = {startDate}/>
      </label>
      <label>
        Enter end date
        <input type = 'date' name ='endDate' onChange={handleChange} value = {endDate}/>
      </label>
      </div>
      <div className='photos'>
      {photos.length && photos.map((photo,index) => {
          return(
            <Photo key = {index} photo = {photo}/>
          )
      })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

***Photo.tsx***

```
import {FC} from 'react'
import {IPhotoComponent} from '../Main'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Photo:FC<IPhotoComponent> = ({children, photo}):JSX.Element  => {


    return(
        <div className='photo'>
            <Link to = {`/photo/${photo.date}`} state = {photo}>
                <img src = {photo.url} />
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Photo
```

***PhotoDetails.tsx***

```
import React, {FC} from 'react'
import { useParams, Params } from 'react-router-dom'
import { IPhoto } from './Main'

const PhotoDetails:FC<IPhoto>= ({state}):JSX.Element => {


    type PhotoParams = {
        id:string
    }

    const {id} = useParams<PhotoParams>()

    return(
        <div>
            this is photo details
        </div>
    )
}

export default PhotoDetails
```

Comment: Just FYI, route state isn't a prop. `PhotoDetails` should be using the `useLocation` hook to access `location.state`.

Comment: @DrewReese whoops - thanks!

Comment: The `Link` `state` prop is declared `any`, and the [`Location`](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#location) object's `state appears to be declared `unknown`. I'm not familiar enough with typescript to even say if you need to specifically type anything other than assigning a type when destructuring from `location.state`.